# Extracting A List Of Phrases From A Large TXT File, And Writing A Single TXT File With Each Phrase (Also the title of that file)

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of terms, and I have large text files containing some of those terms. My task is to come up with one text file for each of the terms in the same directory as the original text file.

**BEFORE**
listofterms.txt (apple cores, peaches, roast beef, things wrapped in nori, etc...)
LargeFileOfFoodWords.txt (ranging from 20-20,000 individual lines of non-duplicated text)

**AFTER**
apple cores.txt, peaches.txt, roast beef.txt, things wrapped in nori.txt (etc...)
LargeFileOfFoodWords.txt (original file, unchanged--or if possible, with all 'listofterms' extracted)

With the following bat file, I am able to do this with a SINGLE word.  However the resultant file contains the paths of ALL files within the directory the batch file resides in. Successive searches also include apple cores.txt, peaches.txt, etc...

So I have some elements working, and need to tweak the following to:

- not search any files but those I choose
- include ONLY extracted text without metadata
- continue searching and writing files until reaching the bottom of my list of search terms

This script will work with any .txt file and give you the resultant "SearchTerm.txt," if you wish to test it yourself.

```
@echo off
set RESULT_FILE="result.txt"
set /p "buck1=Enter Bucket Word or Phrase to find:"
pushd %~p0type NUL > %RESULT_FILE%.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s/-b/l *.txt') 
do (for /f %%c in ('find /i /c "%buck1%" "%%a"') 
do (for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('find /i "%buck1%" "%%a"') 
do if %%c neq 0 echo :`%%f))>>"%RESULT_FILE%".tmp
move %RESULT_FILE%.tmp %buck1%.txt >nul 2>&1
popd
```

Answer (score 2):

this might work for you:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /xg:listofterms.txt LargeFileOfFoodWords.txt') do (type nul>"%%~a.txt"&echo(%%~a>"result.txt")
```

For more help enter `help for` and `help findstr`.